# How to manipulate UITableViewCell after another cell is tapped ? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to manipulate `UITableViewCell` after another cell is tapped ?

I have 3 cells each one has `UIPickerView` the first cell's `userInteractionEnabled` is `true`  but the 2nd and 3rd is `false` .. when the user tap the 1st cell the rest of cells's `userInteractionEnabled` should be `true`

I know I need to use `userInteractionEnabled` but how ? should I hold the cells in variables then manipulate when I need to?

Comment: Do you want check mark like tik mark when you click table view row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read solutions above and are all valid of course, but I prefer a solution like this: I suppose you have an array of object to display (ignoring pattern you're using).

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
   var selected: Bool = false
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var objects: [MyObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // init your objects: 
        // 1stObj.enabled = true
        // 2ndObj.enabled = false
        // 3rdObj.enabled = false
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let obj = self.objects[indexPath.row]
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
         cell.userInteractionEnabled = obj.enabled
         return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        for obj in self.objects {
           obj.selected = !obj.selected
        } 
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I think this solution is more scalable and maintainable, but is my opionion.

### update

For manipulate cell outside of *'cellForRowAtIndexPath'* function, you can do in this way for instance:

```
func manuallyModifyCell(atIndex index: Int, backgroundColor: UIColor = .clearColor()) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but can you tell me if I changed the background color in cellForRowAtIndexPath for the cells which not selectable .. how to make the color white again after tapping the first cell ? I mean how to manipulate the cell object while i'm outside the cellForRowAtIndexPath fun

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to keep track of userInteractionEnabled

```
var selectable: Bool = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.row]
    if selectable {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        if indexPath.row != 0 { // Only first cell is enabled
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        selectable = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO it's better to just reload the cells that are updated (see my answer). Otherwise, this solution is basically the same as the one I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable that holds on to the selection status of the first item:

```
var didSelectFirst = false
```

Then, in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` you can tell the tableview to reload entirely, or just reload the two rows you want to reload.

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    didSelectFirst = true
    // reload all
    tableView.reloadData()
    // reload some
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([
        NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0),
        NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

And in `tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` you can use the `didSelectFirst` variable to change `userInteractionEnabled`

```
if indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 {
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = didSelectFirst
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's working but still there is a problem because in tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath:) I used cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor() , so now how can I make the cells white again ?

Comment: `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` would make the cell white again

Comment: I ment I want them to be white again after they get enabled

Comment: `if didSelectFirst { cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() }` or something like that. `didSelectFirst` keeps track of whether or not the first cell was selected.

Comment: I know that but what I meant is how to manipulate the "cell" while i'm in didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?? should I use the cellForRowAtIndexPath again inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?